# Time machine restoration frozen at "Preparing to restore "Macintosh HD"…*

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, time-machine, restore

I am using Time Machine to restore a new MacBook Pro 16″. I am using an encrypted HDD that's connected with USB 3 for the restoration.

However, since about an hour the Mac is frozen at the step *"Preparing to restore "Macintosh HD"…*.

Is this behavior normal? How long should a restoration take? Or should I restart the Mac?

Comment: I'd at least leave it overnight. If it errors it will tell you, otherwise let it run or you'll just have to start over.

Comment: @Tetsujin Leaving it overnight did not work. :-(
It's still frozen.

Comment: Ugh! OK, hard reboot time, see what happens. If you were doing an initial migration, then it's probably smartest to do a clean install, skip migration, set up a dummy admin account [don't bother with Apple ID etc] & then once you can get to the desktop try a new migration, which will make your 'proper' account. Then you can dump the temp account you made. Let us know how it goes [though it might end up needing to be a new question.]