# Time Machine System Restore: Stuck in "Preparing to restore "Macintosh HD""

Tags: mac, time-machine, restore

I am attempting to do a Time Machine System Restore in order to revert to a previous OS.

I have the full Time Machine backup on a [Seagate external hard drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GQFG4R9). (Update: I also tried with a [SanDisk external SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HN37XC1), but had the same issue.)

However, when I initiate the System Restore, the utility gets stuck on the screen that says "Preparing to restore "Macintosh HD"." I left it on overnight--and 24 hours later it was still stuck on this screen with no signs of progress.

I am running macOS 12.0.1 on a 2017 MacBook Pro 15".

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I found this [topic asking the same question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399958/time-machine-restoration-frozen-at-preparing-to-restore-macintosh-hd) from last year, but no answer was found.

Comment: I am in same situation. Have you ever find a solution?

Comment: I never got the Time Machine System Restore to work, even after multiple calls with Apple support. Essentially, what I ended up needing to do was to re-install the base OS from recovery mode, then use the Time Machine utility to back up after that.